# Open Jquery Div on another page "Hash"

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash

I want to open a div on a different page by using a link.

The links look like this: grid.html # project1 / 2 / 3 / 4 etc..

The code looks like this on the target page:

```
    $(function(){



    // Thumbs
    $('#thumbs a').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('span').stop(true, true).animate({'top': '90px'}, 300)
    },  function(){
        $(this).find('img').stop(true, true).animate({}, 300);
        $(this).find('span').stop(true, true).animate({'top': '124px'}, 300)
    })  .bind('click', function(){
        $('#content .project').stop(true, true).fadeOut(500);
        $($(this).attr('href')).stop(true, true).css('left', 0).fadeIn(500);

        $('#content').animate({'min-height' : '450px', 'display' : 'inline', 'position' : 'relative', 'paddingTop' : '-2px' , 'paddingBottom' : '130px'}, 500); 

        $('#thumbs').animate({'marginTop' : '30px'}, 500);
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 500); 


        return false;
    });

  $(".close").click(function() {
        $('#content .project').fadeOut(500);
        $('#content').animate({'min-height' : '0px', 'display' : 'inline', 'position' : 'relative', 'paddingTop' : '0px' , 'paddingBottom' : '0px'}, 500); 
  });   

    // Carousel
    $('.carousel').jcarousel({
        scroll: 1,
        animation: 800,
        easing: 'easeOutQuart', 
        buttonNextHTML: '<div><div></div></div>',
        buttonPrevHTML: '<div><div></div></div>',
        initCallback: initCarousel
    });



});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
var yourDiv = $('#content .'+hash);
```

Comment: Thanks! It kinda works. Now when i click on a object on the page where the items are on, the link appear in the adress bar, which it didn't did before. However, I can't figure out how to make the link work from another page. The animations I have are stuttering/laging aswell, but that might just be me missplacing the code.

Comment: Surely it should work if you just link to grid.html#project1?

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't. I put the code right after:

$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 500);

Comment: And you replaced all instances of $('#content .project') with yourDiv?

Comment: Yes, unfortunalty it does not work. I have a really hard time to find sites regarding this solution. Anyway, I would gladly take some links on the subject to see if I can learn/see something.